# Android NotificationCompat.Builder works with three buttons but not four

Tags: java, android

I have a notification which includes buttons to control a media player. As implemented below, everything works fine.

```
        Notification notification = builder
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_previous, "", previousPendingIntent)
                // Adding this causes uglyness
//              .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_rewind20, "", jumpBackPendingIntent)
                .addAction(playPauseIcon, "", playPausePendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_next, "", nextPendingIntent)
                .build();

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueid, notification);
```

[image: Working]

However, when I comment out the line

```
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_rewind20, "", jumpBackPendingIntent)
```

The third buttons gets kicked out.

[image: Not Working]

The [Android documentation on this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action)) is pretty sparse. Nothing in the addAction docs implies that there's a limit.

Clearly all of the buttons could fit in the notification. What am I missing?

[Full Source Code](https://github.com/smithdtyler/prettygoodmusicplayer/blob/jumpback/src/com/smithdtyler/prettygoodmusicplayer/MusicPlaybackService.java)

Comment: The docs are sparse, [but there is an internal limit and it's 3.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Notification.java#L1792)

Comment: As you can see the buttons are also meant to have a text caption. In your case a custom view is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Update adneal's link to the [latest code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Notification.java#L3080) here as an answer:

> A notification in its expanded form can display up to 3 actions, from
>   left to right in the order they were added.